# Prove of inradius of a right angle triangle. R²= R1²+ R2²

Tags: geometry, triangles, circles

A right-angle triangle ABC is present whose right angle is BAC. One perpendicular from point A is taken on BC which is AD. Then in triangle ABC, triangle ABD, and triangle ADC, three inscribed circles are drawn with the radius of r, r1 and r2 respectively. Then prove that r^2 = r1^2 + r2^2[Picture Link is attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SeKvn.jpg)

Comment: $\triangle ABC$, $\triangle DBA$ and $\triangle DAC$ are similar. The three ratios of inradius to hypotenuse are the same.

Comment: @peterwhy how are the triangles similar? only the angle 90 and only one side is common.

Comment: For $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle DBA$, $\angle B = \angle ABC = \angle DBA$. For $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle DAC$, $\angle C = \angle BCA = \angle ACD$.

Comment: @peterwhy thanks for the reply. However, can you explain how the three ratios of inradius to hypotenuse are the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the attached figure we have equalizing areas
$$r_1=\frac{CD\times AD}{CD+AD+b}=\frac{bc\cos(\gamma)}{a\cos(\gamma)+a+c}\\r_2=\frac{DB\times AD}{DB+AD+c}=\frac{bc\sin(\gamma)}{a\sin(\gamma)+a+b}\\r=\frac{bc}{a+b+c}$$ so we have to verify that
$$\left(\frac{bc\cos(\gamma)}{a\cos(\gamma)+a+c}\right)^2+\left(\frac{bc\sin(\gamma)}{a\sin(\gamma)+a+b}\right)^2=\left(\frac{bc}{a+b+c}\right)^2$$
Since $a\cos(\gamma)=b$ and     $a\sin(\gamma)=c$ we have finally to verify that
$$(bc\sin(\gamma))^2+(bc\cos(\gamma))^2=(bc)^2$$
We are done.

[image]